# Idiomatic Type Conversion in Go

Tags: go

I was playing around with Go and was wondering what the best way is to perform idiomatic type conversions in Go. Basically my problem lays within automatic type conversions between `uint8`, `uint64`, and `float64`. From my experience with other languages a multiplication of a `uint8` with a `uint64` will yield a `uint64` value, but not so in go.

Here is an example that I build and I ask if this is the idiomatic way of writing this code or if I'm missing an important language construct.

```
package main

import ("math";"fmt")

const(Width=64)

func main() {

    var index uint32
    var bits uint8

    index = 100
    bits = 3

    var c uint64
    // This is the line of interest vvvv
    c = uint64(math.Ceil(float64(index * uint32(bits))/float64(Width)))
    fmt.Println("Test: %v\n", c)
}
```

From my point of view the calculation of the ceiling value seems unnecessary complex because of all the explicit type conversions.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the floating point math? http://play.golang.org/p/kdV9vnIqPN

Comment: Imagine you have a two 64 bits wide blocks storing 8 bit integers and you want to store 9 elements and need to know how many blocks to allocate without overhead. 9*8/64 = 1, but 8*8/64=1 as well. Maybe I'm missing an interesting +/- 1 thing here...

Comment: Use: (9*8+(64-1))/64 = 2 and (8*8+(64-1))/64 = 1. See my answer.

Comment: `float64(b[0])` to set an uint8/byte to a float64. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725637/12817546.
`byte(f)` to set a float64 to an uint8/byte. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62753031/12817546.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no implicit type conversions for non-constant values.

You can write

```
var x float64
x = 1
```

But you cannot write

```
var x float64
var y int

y = 1
x = y
```

See [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) for reference.

There's a good reason, to not allow automatic/implicit type conversions, as they can
become very messy and one has to learn many rules to circumvent the various caveats
that may occur. Take the [Integer Conversion Rules in C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) for example.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func CeilUint(a, b uint64) uint64 {
    return (a + (b - 1)) / b
}

func main() {
    const Width = 64
    var index uint32 = 100
    var bits uint8 = 3
    var c uint64 = CeilUint(uint64(index)*uint64(bits), Width)
    fmt.Println("Test:", c)
}
```

Output:

```
Test: 5
```

Comment: Even though it's correct in it's own way. The other answer was the one I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add to @nemo terrific answer. The convenience of automatic conversion between numeric types in C is outweighed by the confusion it causes. See https://Golang.org/doc/faq#conversions. Thats why you can't even convert from int to int32 implicitly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13852456/12817546.

```
package main

import (
    . "fmt"
    . "strconv"
)

func main() {
    i := 71
    c := []interface{}{byte(i), []byte(string(i)), float64(i), i, rune(i), Itoa(i), i != 0}
    checkType(c)
}

func checkType(s []interface{}) {
    for k, _ := range s {
        Printf("%T %v\n", s[k], s[k])
    }
}
```

`byte(i)` creates a uint8 with a value of 71, `[]byte(string(i))` a []uint8 with [71], `float64(i)` float64 71, `i` int 71, `rune(i)` int32 71, `Itoa(i)` string 71 and `i != 0` a bool with a value of true.

Since Go won't convert numeric types automatically for you (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13851553/12817546) you have to convert between types manually. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41419962/12817546. Note, Itoa(i) sets an "Integer to an ASCII". See comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10105983/12817546.

Comment: A boolean, numeric, or string type can be set to another type. For`[]byte` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725637/12817546, for `float64` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62753031/12817546, `int` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546, `string` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546 and for `bool` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62726854/12817546.