# Casting between number types in golang

Tags: casting, go, numeric

Could someone please tell me if go supports automatic casting of numeric types. Right now I have to manually convert the results of all my computation to int or int64 and keep track of what numeric type I am using.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question and it's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367979/idiomatic-type-conversion-in-go/13368417).

Answer (score 15):

Go won't convert numeric types automatically for you.

From the language specification:

> Conversions are required when different numeric types are mixed in
>   an expression or assignment. For instance, int32 and int are not
>   the same type even though they may have the same size on a particular
>   architecture.

Answer (score 5):

Go does not support implicit type conversions in numeric type.

Refer [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types). I think this is for reasons of safety and predictability. One more thing I found was a bit weird/interesting is that you cant even convert from int to int32 implicitly, which is weird cause both are of the same size.

[image: type conversion]
[image: error]

Comment: `int` is most certainly not specified as `int32`.  It varies by implementation and platform.

Comment: So how do you do it explicit?

Comment: `int` and `int32` are not necessarily the same Type: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types

Comment: Illuminating answer. I quoted you here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert between types manually, e.g.

```
var b byte = byte(x % 256);
```

Comment: Elucidate answer I quoted. Did I add to it? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546