# Converting between rune and byte (slice)

Tags: go

Go allows conversion from `rune` to `byte`. But the underlying type for `rune` is `int32` (because Go uses UTF-8) and for `byte` it is `uint8`, the conversion therefore results in a loss of information. However it is not possible to convert from a rune to `[]byte`.

```
var b byte = '©'
bs := []byte(string('©'))
fmt.Println(b)
fmt.Println(bs)

// Output
169
[194 169]
```

[Working example](https://play.golang.org/p/14m9YDhVnbA)

Why does Go allow conversion from `rune` to `byte` instead of `rune` to `[]byte`?

Comment: The reason one conversion works and the other not is because those are the rules of the language spec. For more details on conversion you can read this: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions. If you're asking *why* the authors chose those specific rules then you'll have to ask the authors themselves, and you can try the go-nuts mailing list to do that, the authors do interact with the users there.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. Does this partly answer it? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62739051/12817546

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go supports conversion from `rune` to `byte` as it does for all pairs of numeric types.  It would be a surprising special case if `int32` to `byte` conversion was not allowed.

> But the underlying type for `rune` is `int32` (because Go uses UTF-8)

This misses an important detail: `rune` is an alias for `int32`.  They are the same type.

It's true that the underlying type is `rune` is `int32`, but that's because `rune` and `int32` are the same type and the underlying type of a builtin type is the type itself.

The representation of Unicode code points as `int32` values is unrelated to UTF-8 encoding.

> the conversion therefore results in a loss of information

Yes, conversions between numeric types can result in loss of information.  This is one reason why conversions in Go must be explicit.

Note that the statement `var b byte = '©'` does not do any conversions.  The expression `'@'` is an untyped constant.

The compiler reports an error if the assignment of an untyped constant results in a loss of information.  For example, the statement `var b byte = '世'` causes a compilation error.

All UTF-8 encoding functionality in the language is related to the `string` type. The UTF-8 aware conversions are all to or from the `string` type.  The `[]byte(numericType)` conversion could be supported, but that would bring UTF-8 encoding outside of the `string` type.

The Go authors regret including the `string(numericType)` conversion because it's not very useful in practice and the conversion is not what some people  expect. A library function is a better place for the functionality.

Comment: Use `b2 := '©'` to get "int32 169" and `var b byte = '©'` to get “uint8 169".
Likewise use r := '世' to get “int32 19990” and `byte(r)` to get “uint8 22”. See https://play.golang.org/p/IcufRCuzFk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to convert from a rune to []byte (for example via a byte) and back again.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var b byte = '©'
    bs := []byte{b}
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", b, b)   // uint8 169
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", bs, bs) // []uint8 [169]

    s := string(bs[0]) // s := string(b) works too.
    r2 := rune(s[0]) // r2 := rune(b) works too.
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", s, s) // string ©
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", r2, r2) // int32 169
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this behaviour is the same reason why it's legal to do

```
var b int32
b = 1000000
fmt.Printf("%b\n", b)
fmt.Printf("%b", uint8(b))

// Output:
// 11110100001001000000
// 1000000
```

You should expect the conversion to loose data when you put data of a type with larger memory footprint into one with a smaller memory footprint.

Also, for encoding a `rune` you can use [EncodeRune](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#EncodeRune) which indeed uses a `[]byte`.