# Convert rune to int?

Tags: go, type-conversion, idioms, rune

In the following code, I iterate over a `string` rune by rune, but I'll actually need an `int` to perform some checksum calculation. Do I really need to encode the `rune` into a `[]byte`, then convert it to a `string` and then use `Atoi` to get an `int` out of the `rune`? Is this the idiomatic way to do it?

```
// The string `s` only contains digits.
var factor int
for i, c := range s[:12] {
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        factor = 1
    } else {
        factor = 3
    }
    buf := make([]byte, 1)
    _ = utf8.EncodeRune(buf, c)
    value, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(buf))
    sum += value * factor
}
```

On the playground: http://play.golang.org/p/noWDYjn5rJ

Comment: `int(r)` to set a rune to an int. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62739051/12817546. `rune(i)` to set an int to a rune. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The problem is simpler than it looks. You convert a `rune` value to an `int` value with `int(r)`. But your code implies you want the integer value out of the ASCII (or UTF-8) representation of the digit, which you can trivially get with `r - '0'` as a `rune`, or `int(r - '0')` as an `int`. Be aware that out-of-range runes will corrupt that logic.

Comment: For those who is wondering how `int(r-'0')` even work, short explanation: "subtracting the value of rune '0' from any rune '0' through '9' will give you an integer 0 through 9". Resulting type after subtraction `r-'0'` will be int32 (base type of runes), that is why if you need `int` type - you will also need `int()` conversion.

Answer (score 15):

For example, `sum += (int(c) - '0') * factor`,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    s := "9780486653556"
    var factor, sum1, sum2 int
    for i, c := range s[:12] {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            factor = 1
        } else {
            factor = 3
        }
        buf := make([]byte, 1)
        _ = utf8.EncodeRune(buf, c)
        value, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(buf))
        sum1 += value * factor
        sum2 += (int(c) - '0') * factor
    }
    fmt.Println(sum1, sum2)
}
```

Output:

```
124 124
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I want. You are initializing the rune with 42 - that would yield the `*` character according to my ASCII table. What I get is a string and `range` yields runes, that represent the the character. Using int on the rune would give me the value of the representation, not the *display* value, which I need. I made a short snippet, that hints at the difference: http://play.golang.org/p/JLlmKnddGv

Comment: @miku: see my revised answer.

Comment: Ah, nice trick. I don't know why your answer has been downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

why don't you do only  "string(rune)".

```
s:="12345678910"
var factor,sum int
for i,x:=range s{
    if i%2==0{
            factor=1
        }else{
        factor=3
    }
        xstr:=string(x) //x is rune converted to string
        xint,_:=strconv.Atoi(xstr)
        sum+=xint*factor
}
fmt.Println(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(v))
```

Where v is a rune

More concise but same idea as above

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix for `sum2`

`sum2 += (int(c) - '0') * factor`

Convert `int` to `rune` -> `int(rune)`, getting integer for specific ASCII character, just subtract it.

Example `int('1') - '0' = 1`.

`'0' -> 48`

`'1' -> 49`

`49 - 48 = 1`

For English alphabet it will be ASCII values.

```
fmt.Println("ASCII  48, val 0 = ", int('0'))
fmt.Println("ASCII  57, val 9 = ", int('9'))

fmt.Println("ASCII  65, val A = ", int('A'))
fmt.Println("ASCII  90, val Z = ", int('Z'))

fmt.Println("ASCII  97, val a = ", int('a'))
fmt.Println("ASCII 122, val z = ", int('z'))
```

But for non English characters, it will be Non ASCII values, or rather greater than ASCII:

```
// Cyrillic
fmt.Println("Non ASCII = 1071", int('Я'))
fmt.Println("Non ASCII = 1044", int('Д'))

// Chinese
fmt.Println("Non ASCII = 19990", int('世'))
fmt.Println("Non ASCII = 30028", int('界'))
```

https://go.dev/play/p/2fhM7DGZ4Km