# Error converting interface{} to int go-gin

Tags: go, interface, type-conversion

I have an `interface{}` type value received from `*gin.Context`:

```
c.MustGet("account")
```

When I try to convert this into `int` using :

```
c.MustGet("account").(int)
```

I get an error:

```
interface conversion: interface is float64, not int
```

The value of this interface is `1`. Why am I receiving this error? I am using this value in a sql query. I cannot convert this to `float64` as the sql statement fails then. How can I convert this into `int`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022389/convert-a-float64-to-an-int-in-go?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The error is rather self-explanatory: the dynamic value stored in the `interface{}` value is of type `float64` which is different from the type `int`.

Extract a value of type `float64` (using [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) as you did), and do the conversion using a simple [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
f := c.MustGet("account").(float64)
i := int(f)
// i is of type int, you may use it so
```

Or in one line:

```
i := int(c.MustGet("account").(float64))
```

To verify the type and value:

```
fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", i, i)
```

Output in both cases (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/z12-nf9NiY)):

```
int 1
```